# Envio de mail automatico - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación de ***windows forms*** ya creada en el visual studio (c#), que al hacer click sobre un botón envía un **email** con un adjunto.

Lo que necesito es evitar tener un usuario haciendo click en el botón, y en vez, automatizar el proceso para que el email se envíe solo a determinado horario. ¿Cómo podría hacer?

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo:

1. Colocar todo el código de la operación en un método o función, por ejemplo en `enviarcorreo();`. Si desde el evento onclick del botón necesitas enviar el correo, solo ejecutar la función, por ejemplo `enviarcorreo();`
2. Usar un `Timer` para ejecutar cada cierto tiempo la función de `enviarcorreo();`
3. En vez de usar `Timer` puedes usar un loop infinito con `while`o `for`, en tal caso te recomiendo uses una función `async enviarcorreo(){}` y `await` para enviar el correo, en tal caso se enviará el siguiente correo, en cuanto haya terminado con el proceso actual.

Suerte!!!

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero ayudanos a responder preguntas que estén realizadas con respecto al [help], saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! ¿Se podría de la manera que mencionas, evitar la interfaz gráfica (la cual actualmente tiene solo el botón anteriormente mencionado)?

Comment: Se podría, pero en ese caso deberías usar una tarea en segundo plano. Siempre es recomendable tener un mecanismo de verificación de que la tarea está funcionando. Desde dicho thread puedes usar un delegado para actualizar una una interfaz gráfica.